Can not use the vue headless ui combobox scrollbar inside the Tab or Radio Group components
I can not use the scrollbar inside the headless UI Tab Component, when I click and scroll the scrollbar, the combo box will close.ComboBoxInput is giving issue for closing the scroll bar.
the moment I click inside the scrollbar the Combobox is closed because the Tab component moves focus to the Tab element itself and therefore blurs the Combobox which closes the combobox.
What package within Headless UI are you using?
@headlessui/vue
What version of that package are you using?
v1.7.19
What browser are you using?
Chrome
Vue version- 3.3.10

<TabGroup>
<TabList class="flex gap-6 p-2 pb-0">
                      <Tab
                        as="template"
                        :key="'1"
                        v-slot="{ selected }"
                      >
                    <button
                    :class="[
                        'py-2.5 px-1 text-left text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500',
                        'focus:outline-none',
                        selected ? 'border-b-2 border-blue-600 text-blue-600' : ''
                      ]"
                    >
                  <spanTab</span> 
                    </button>
               </Tab>
       <TabPanels class="mt-2">
              <TabPanel
              :key="'2'"
              :class="[
                      'rounded-lg bg-white  shadow-md',
                      'focus:outline-none ring-white ring-opacity-60 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-blue-400 focus:ring-2'
                    ]">    
            <Combobox v-model="selected">
      <div class="relative mt-1">
        <div
          class="relative w-full cursor-default overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white/75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-teal-300 sm:text-sm"
        >
          <ComboboxInput
            class="w-full border-none py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:ring-0"
            :displayValue="(person) => person.name"
            @change="query = $event.target.value"
          />
          <ComboboxButton
            class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2"
          >
            <ChevronUpDownIcon
              class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          </ComboboxButton>
        </div>
        <TransitionRoot
          leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
          @after-leave="query = ''"
        >
          <ComboboxOptions
            class="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black/5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
          >
            <div
              v-if="filteredPeople.length === 0 && query !== ''"
              class="relative cursor-default select-none px-4 py-2 text-gray-700"
            >
              Nothing found.
            </div>

            <ComboboxOption
              v-for="person in filteredPeople"
              as="template"
              :key="person.id"
              :value="person"
              v-slot="{ selected, active }"
            >
              <li
                class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4"
                :class="{
                  'bg-teal-600 text-white': active,
                  'text-gray-900': !active,
                }"
              >
                <span
                  class="block truncate"
                  :class="{ 'font-medium': selected, 'font-normal': !selected }"
                >
                  {{ person.name }}
                </span>
                <span
                  v-if="selected"
                  class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3"
                  :class="{ 'text-white': active, 'text-teal-600': !active }"
                >
                  <CheckIcon class="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                </span>
              </li>
            </ComboboxOption>
          </ComboboxOptions>
        </TransitionRoot>
      </div>
    </Combobox>
              </TabPanel>
        </TabPanels>
    </TabGroup>

I can not use the scrollbar inside the headless UI Tab Component, when I click and scroll the scrollbar, the combo box will close.ComboBoxInput is giving issue for closing the scroll bar. comboBox scroll bar should not be closed when its is added inside the tab component .

Try using preventDefault() on blur.

Adding  tabIndex=-1 inside the  <ComboboxOption solves the issue.
